# Multiple widgetized sidebars in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, widget, sidebar

I have succesfuly created multiple wordpress widgetized sidebars with my functions.php file with the following code

```
<?php
    if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
        register_sidebar(array('name' => 'mrskitson'));
        register_sidebar(array('name' => 'mrskitson2'));
    } 
?>
```

However When I try and include them in a page only the first one shows up even when I specify the second one by name. The code for that is below.

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('mrskitson2') ) : ?>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
        register_sidebar(array('name' => 'mrskitson','id' => 'mrskitson'));
        register_sidebar(array('name' => 'mrskitson2','id' => 'mrskitson2'));
    }
```

Try including an ID, I believe that is what it is keyed on.

Comment: Still shows the first one 'mrskitson' Do I need to do anything different when I call the dynamic_sidebar.